# How to use the ZoomCenter instruction of pyautocad?

Tags: python-3.x, autocad-plugin, autocad-scripts

1:I use pyautocad to conture my AutoCAD .
2：Now,I have a question is that I don't knowen how to use a foundation "acad.app.ZoomCenter" in pyautocad.
3:I search help (acad.app.ZoomCenter)，but it only has Refers to a simple description.
4:So I excuse "how to use foundation "acad.app.ZoomCenter" in pyautocad?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider to give some extra details in your comments.